# Is it possible to use column selection in Eclipse by holding down keys (instead of entering a whole 'mode')?

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

In Visual Studio I can do column/block-selection by holding <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> and using the arrow keys.

I know that in Eclipse I can press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> to enter the column selection mode, then hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> and use the arrow keys.

Is there a way to do the column selection without entering a whole mode (and having to exit the mode afterwards), by e.g. just holding down some keys like in Visual Studio?